# What erector sets will function with normal servo motors?

Tags: mobile-robot, rcservo

I need a basic erector set that the parts will fit with servo motors and dc motors. Preferably below $100. I've looked at [Minds-i basic set](http://mindsirobotics.com/250-piece-basic-construction-set.html) and it looks good except I don't know if it will function with my servos without hot glue or extensive modifications.

If it matters, I am making a bipedal robot so I don't require any wheels or anything pre-built. I just need a basic set that I can add on to to build a whole bunch of different robots.

Comment: Bumping your question twice in 3 hours was not only poor manners, it probably didn't help you reach any wider audience.  Not everyone here checks this website every day, let alone every hour.  If you are having a robotics-related emergency, a chat forum may be a better place to look for real-time help.

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need to bump your post with edits. 6 new questions in a day seems to be pretty busy around here. You ask at 6pm on a Sunday - probably nobody was around.

Second, I don't think there is a "standard" servo mount, so no kit is going to give you what you're looking for. The mounting pattern varies by manufacturer and model so you need to pick a servo and look for a mount for that particular one.

Third, I'm not sure why you would go for an [85 dollar, 240 piece](http://mindsirobotics.com/250-piece-basic-construction-set.html) knock-off LEGO kit when a genuine [204 piece kit is 60 dollars](https://shop.education.lego.com/legoed/en-US/catalog/product.jsp?productId=9689&isSimpleSearch=false&ProductLine=Machines-%26-Mechanisms). Genuine LEGO sets give you guaranteed compatibility with all of their other stuff, like motors, pneumatics, and the mindstorm equipment.

Fourth, I don't know why you are willing to invest so much in a kit to mount servos when the basic servo bracket costs between [2 and 5 dollars](https://www.google.com/search?q=servo+mounting+bracket&tbm=shop). For 85 dollars you could buy 15-40 servo brackets.

Fifth, if you leave LEGO kits behind and just go for a servo bracket, you can check out other kits that are good for building things. Ironically, your question states you are looking for "a basic erector set", but you link an 85 dollar, 240 piece generic LEGO kit when you could buy [an actual 640 piece Erector set](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000GOF5S2) for 80 dollars.